# template characters not used in html

Tags: html

A simple but tricky question in HTML for me. 
I want to store a template

```
 <a class="mylink" href="#">@</a>
```

Inside a file. Characters `#` and `@` are to be replaced at runtime. My question is that are `#` and `@` the best characters to be used in this case and will never conflict? or Does anybody have a better idea?

**Update:**

The program that does the replacement is in C++ and the HTML is generated for local host purpose. It is not a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are the best characters depends on your implementation. A problem I see with `#` is that this character is also used for internal links (e.g. `<a href="#top">top</a>`.

I think it would be a better solution to use PHP/ASP/TheLanguageYouUse-Tags like this: `<a class="mylink" href="<?php echo getLinkAdress("linkName"); ?>"><?php echo getLinkContent("linkName"); ?></a>`

Comment: Indeed. If no server language, use something that will be very unlikely to match, like `$$$replacement###`.

Comment: The program that does the replacement is C++ and the HTML is generated for local host purpose

Comment: Then you should use something linke Patrick Hofmann wrote. You can also have a look at the Smarty Template Engine for inspiration: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/de/language.variables.tpl

Comment: As i told, it depends on your exactly needs :) But the possibility, that you want to output this tag and not replace it is probably very low, so there is no problem using it.